# How to add data to the last empty column using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to go to the last column with value and insert data to the column to the right that does not contain value, below is the code I have, and it isn't showing the result I wanted. Any help would be appreciated. My main objective is whenever I run the vba, it will insert new data to the next column. Example, I have a range of data from A1 to D2, when I run the vba macro, it will insert new data to E1 and E2.

```
    Dim LastCol As Long
    Dim lrngCol As Range
    
    LastCol = ws1.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToRight).Column
    Set lrngCol = Cells(1, LastCol)
    lrngCol.Formula = "=CONCATENATE(" & """" & "Test Name " & """" & "," & rng1.Offset(-1, 4).Address & ")"
    lrngCol.Offset(2, 0).Formula2 = "=SORT(UNIQUE(FILTER(H2:H100,H2:H100<>" & """""" & ")))"
```

Comment: `ws1.Cells(1, Columns.Count)` is the last cell (right-most) on row1, `End(xlToRight)` locates the cell on the right edge. So `ws1.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToRight).Column` equals `Columns.Count`.  _Microsoft documentation:_

> [Range.End property (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.end?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initialize Variables.
Locate Last Occupied Column.
Increment Column Index.
Data Insertion.

```
Sub InsertDataIntoNextColumn()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim LastCol As Long
    
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1") ' Specify the correct sheet name
    
    ' Find the last used column in the first row and add 1 to target the next empty column
    LastCol = ws.Cells(1, ws.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column + 1
    
    ' Insert data into the next column for the first two rows
    ws.Cells(1, LastCol).Value = "Test Name"  ' Change as needed
    ws.Cells(2, LastCol).Value = "New Data"   ' Change as needed
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you it does add value to the last column

Comment: You're welcome, glad I was able to help!

Answer (score 1):

Use `xlToLeft` instead of `xlToRight`. Also increment 1 to put value to last non empty cell of last data entry column. Try-

```
Sub lColData()
    Dim LastCol As Long
    Dim lrngCol As Range
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet
    
    Set ws1 = Worksheets("Sheet1")
    LastCol = ws1.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column + 1
    Set lrngCol = Cells(1, LastCol)
    lrngCol = "Last Col Value"
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi i tried your code but it isn't working, it is not adding data to the next column.